# Button click function not getting called in Typecsript

Tags: angularjs, button, typescript, hawtio

I am facing an issue while dynamically creating Button element in Typescript.
I am reading the properties from external config and accordingly creating buttons.

The buttons appear on the screen. Only the 'click' functionality doesn't get applied. i tried giving alert on button click, which does not appear on clicking the buttons. No error , no output.

Following is my code snippet:

```
for(var i=0; i< myArr.length; i++)
                     {
                       var button1 = document.createElement('button');
                       button1.textContent = "Connect To button " + [i];
                       button1.click = function()
                     {
                         alert("inside btn click function ");
                     }
                      docContent.appendChild(button1);
                     };
```

Can anyone help figure out what needs to be changed?

Comment: why would you want to programatically create buttons?

Comment: Its a requirement to connect to different servers on button click, taking parameters from external config file . I am newbie to typescript.so asked  the question.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to attach an click event listener to you button like so :

```
button1.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    //This would be your callback function for the click event on button
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The default event listener is "onclick", not "click". Just to:

```
button1.onclick = function() {alert('Clicked!');}
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xk6ukLav/).